# ошибка в шифре цезаря

Tags: python

Pешил сделать функцию шифра цезаря. В первом аргументе искомая строка, во втором сдвиг. Если второй аргумент больше 11 или слишком большой текст код зацикливается. Как можно решить данную проблему(если не сложно, можно не менять коренную структуру кода)

```
def match(text, alphabet=set('абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя')):
    return alphabet.isdisjoint(text.lower())

def CesarCodeRu(text3, number):

    alphabet = ["а","б","в","г","д","е","ё","ж","з","и","й","к","л","м","н","о",
        "п","р","с","т","у","ф","х","ц","ч","ш","щ","ъ","ы","ь","э","ю","я"]
    # уборка лишних пробелов  
    text2 = text3.replace(' ','')
    # преобразование к нижнему регистру
    text1 = text2.lower()
    # разбитие строки на массив
    text = list(text1)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    newText = []
    # Проверка на русский алфавит
    if match(text1):
        return 'invalid text'
    # проверка на валидность сдвига
    if number > 33 or number < -33:
        return 'invalid number'
    # Если число равно 0 или 33 или -33 то возвращение исходной строки
    if number == 0 or number == 33 or number == -33:
        return ''.join(text)
    # Первый цикл идет по text
    # второй меняет каждую букву на сдвиг
    while i < len(text):
        while j <= len(alphabet): 
            stoping = j + number                        
            if  stoping >= 33:
                j = number - 32
            elif stoping <= -33:
               j = number + 32
            # Если буква в строке text равна букве алфавита
            # то добавляем в массив "сдвиг"
            elif text[i] == alphabet[j]:
                newText.append( alphabet[j + number])
                # Остановка цикла 
                break
            j = j + 1
        i = i + 1
    return ''.join(newText)  

print(CesarCodeRu('Мама мыла раму', 5))
```

Comment: Попробовал с 15 (это больше 11), код нормально отработал.

Comment: если поставить 25-30 все сломается)

Comment: А битовый сдвиг не легче применить?

Comment: Может быть и легче, но я хочу разобраться почему не работает в таком виде, алгоритмически вроде бы все правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий код, попытался сохранить общую структуру вашего кода:

```
def match(text, alphabet=set('абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя')):
    return alphabet.isdisjoint(text.lower())

def CesarCodeRu(text3, number):
    alphabet='абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
    # убираем лишние пробелы, приводим в нижний регистр
    text = text3.replace(' ','').lower()
    # проверяем текст на содержание иностранных букв
    if match(text):
        return 'invalid text'
    # проверка на валидность сдвига
    if number>33 or number<-33:
        return 'invalid number'
    # если сдвиг 0 или 33 или -33, то вернем введенную строку
    if number in [0,33,-33]:
        return text

    new_text=''
    # цикл идет побуквенно
    for letter in text:
        # создаем новую позицию: ищем позицию буквы и добавляем сдвиг
        new_pos = alphabet.find(letter)+number
        # если новая позиция больше длины алфавита - вычитаем из нее длину
        if new_pos > len(alphabet)-1:
            new_pos -= len(alphabet)
        # добавляем в новую строку полученный символ
        new_text += alphabet[new_pos]

    return new_text

print(CesarCodeRu('АБВ', 32))
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, но можете прокомментировать код, я хочу разобраться почему так, заранее спасибо:)

Comment: @E_R_H_A_N добавил комментарии.

Comment: хотя я и не понимаю смысл этой проверки, я ее оставил

    if number>33 or number<-33: